# Is there a way to set character values at the top of an R program such that you don't have to make multiple changes at each run

Tags: r

I'm working on a rather lengthy shared R program which processes client data and references things like the name of the time variables supplied by each client (which obviously changes at almost every client submission).

What I wanted to do is to set the name of (say) a timeseries variable to WEEK and be able to reference timeseries throughout the code so that I only need to change the one section of code right at the top:

**TOP OF CODE**

```
timeseries <- "WEEK"
```

**EXAMPLE MID CODE**

```
summary_transposed_no_time = summary_transposed_no_missing
summary_transposed_no_time$timeseries <- NULL
```

I have found that this approach does work for things like sqldf steps as the below is working just fine. Ideally I want to use this approach across both R logic and SQL logic as the program is very lengthy and a lot of it is written in SQL which I would love to avoid re-writing:

```
dataset <- "client_a_data"
response <- "SALE"
timeseries <- "WEEK"
region <- "POSTAL_DIST"

summary <- sqldf(paste("SELECT",timeseries,
                       ",",region,
                       ",sum(",response,") AS", response,
                       "FROM", "dataset",
                       "GROUP BY",timeseries,"," ,region,
                       "ORDER BY",timeseries,"," ,region
                       )
)
```

Comment: Yes, you can reuse values by assigning variables in R.  Yes, you can reuse chunks of code (by defining functions).  At the moment this question is too general to be useful.  Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I dont understand what seems to be the problem? You save data in a variable and then use the variable name throughout the program...?

Comment: Thanks both, the specific problem is that `timeseries <- "WEEK"
summary_transposed_no_time = summary_transposed_no_missing
summary_transposed_no_time$timeseries <- NULL` doesn't seem to work to remove the column week from the data frame summary_transposed_no_time. If I remove the "s from around WEEK then R seems to think I'm tryign to reference a data frame column

Comment: you need to use `[[timeseries]]` instead of `$timeseries`

Comment: In sqldf one would normally use fn$ for string interpolation like this:
`fn$sqldf("select $timeseries, $region, sum($response) as $response 
from $dataset
group by $timeseries, $region order by $timeseries, $region")`     
For more examples search sqldf home page for fn$ :  https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to achieve, but let me know if I'm off track...

One way I can see to do this would be to build a search for the appropriate column early in your script, and use the returned value from then on to refer to column.

```
df <- data.frame( data = rnorm( 20, 1, 1 ), day = seq_len( 20 ) )
df$week <- ((df$day - 1) %/% 7) + 1
```

Now we can specify your `timeseries` variable as any of the columns in the frame:

```
timeseries <- "week"
```

Then, somewhere in our script, have something like this to extract a reference for the column:

```
timeColumn <- match( timeseries, names( df ) )
```

Which now allows you to refer to that column as many times as you like in your script:

```
df[, timeColumn]
```

Any time you change that "week" value to, say "day", the rest of your script will now change to refer to that instead.

Just a note, if you do go this route, be careful to either not move columns around (making your reference value stop working correctly) or have the `match` call run each time you want to refer to the column (this would allow you to move columns around if you need to).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to any column by name directly. Variables `response`, `timeseries` and `region` are as defined in the question.

```
# generate some data
client_a_data <- data.frame(SALE=100:104, WEEK=1:5, POSTAL_DIST=60000:60004)

# read in data
dataset <- ... # whatever code you use to upload the client_a_data
# here:
dataset <- "client_a_data"
dataset <- get(dataset)
dataset
  SALE WEEK POSTAL_DIST
1  100    1       60000
2  101    2       60001
3  102    3       60002
4  103    4       60003
5  104    5       60004

# refer to any column by its pre-defined name

dataset[, timeseries]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

dataset[, c(response, region)]
  SALE POSTAL_DIST
1  100       60000
2  101       60001
3  102       60002
4  103       60003
5  104       60004
```

So your specific line that would delete the WEEK column should read:

```
summary_transposed_no_time[, timeseries] <- NULL
```

Or you might wish to rename the pertaining columns at the beginning of your code to whatever text appears throughout.

```
colnames(dataset)[match(c(timeseries, response, region), colnames(dataset))] <- c("timeseries", "response", "region")
```